# How to provide unique id to a button in a JSP loop

Tags: java, html, jsp

I would like to give each button in the loop a unique ID to associate the button id to that particular row.

Any help in this matter would be highly appreciated!

```
while(resultSet.next()){
%>
    <tr bgcolor="#DEB887">

        <td><%=resultSet.getString("productid") %></td>
        <td><%=resultSet.getString("productname") %></td>
        <td><%=resultSet.getInt("price") %></td>
        <td><%=resultSet.getString("quantity") %></td>
        <td><%=resultSet.getString("totalprice") %></td>
        <td><button id=  type="button" onclick="addToCart()">Add to Cart</button></td>
    </tr>

    <%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing your own looping... You could use an int variable and use it to increment for each iteration ... see the example below;

```
<%
int idCounter=1;
while(resultSet.next()){
%>
    <tr bgcolor="#DEB887">

        <td><%=resultSet.getString("productid") %></td>
        <td><%=resultSet.getString("productname") %></td>
        <td><%=resultSet.getInt("price") %></td>
        <td><%=resultSet.getString("quantity") %></td>
        <td><%=resultSet.getString("totalprice") %></td>
        <td><button id="addToCartButtonId<%=idCounter%>"  type="button" onclick="addToCart()">Add to Cart</button></td>
    </tr>

    <% 
       idCounter++;
%>
```

For each row, the button will have a unique id.
Hope this helps ...

Thanks.